# Is there a way to unhook a global hotkey in windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I'm running Windows 7, and I installed an application that installed a global hot key (ctrl+shift+space) which conflicts with another application (Visual Studio) that uses that hotkey (though, not globally, only applications specific).

The question is, knowing which application it is (ScanSnap Manager) and that it doesn't have a setting to turn off the hot key, is there a way I disable it through Windows somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If it's conflicting with Visual Studio, you can use [Autohotkey](http://autohotkey.com) to send the keys to the Visual Studio window.

I don't know if all VS applications use the same window class, but Visual C# uses `wndclass_desked_gsk`. You can determine the class used with the Window Spy utility that comes packaged with Autohotkey.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class wndclass_desked_gsk
^+space::ControlSend, ,^+space,ahk_class wndclass_desked_gskit
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: Yup . Autohotkey is the best thing I know  :)

Comment: Wow... works for me... I'm not sure why you put "wndclass_desked_gskit" rather than "wndclass_desked_gsk"... I just put the class name, which I found with a simple AHK script which I have had the temerity to add to your answer...