# How can I remove a default key binding in Windows Terminal

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-terminal

I'm using the new Windows Terminal app and trying to change the full-screen toggle from F11 to Shift-F11.  I know how to add Shift-F11, but I can't seem to figure out how to remove F11.  I could change the "defaults.json" file, but the changes would be lost every time the app updates.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your `settings.json` file, you can unset key bindings by creating a command whose action is `null`. You can also overwrite defaults.

In your case, try using this config:

```
//settings.json

...

"keybindings":
    [
        ...

        { "command": "toggleFullscreen", "keys": "shift+f11" },
        { "command": null, "keys": "f11" }
    ]
```

From [Using Editing Windows Terminal JSON Settings](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/master/doc/user-docs/UsingJsonSettings.md):

> ```
> {
>     "command" : null, "keys" : ["ctrl+shift+6"]
> },
> ```
>
> This will unbind Ctrl+Shift+6, allowing vim to use the keystroke instead of the terminal.

And:

> Any changes in that profile will overwrite those from the defaults.

Comment: In place of null, use unbound in double quotes like "unbound" in new terminal

Answer (score 4):

Since Windows Terminal v1.4 the `"keybindings"` key has been deprecated in favour of `"actions"`. [Customize actions in Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/actions)

Both `null` and `"unbound"` commands will work.

```json
"actions":
[
    { "command": "unbound", "keys": "f11" }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

(the only way it worked for me)

you can add

```
{ "command": { "action": "sendInput", "input": "\u0000" }, "keys": "ctrl+shift+up" },
{ "command": { "action": "sendInput", "input": "\u0000" }, "keys": "ctrl+shift+down" },
```

so when you press the keys, it replaces the undesirable command with sending a null character to the input (that, of course, does nothing lol)